# How to pass php variable to function in separate file and get results back without submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

i have used car selling site. users can post their car for sale. I want users should be able to see the expected price of their car when they click on expected price field without submitting the from. function input is to be passed as variable. Se  below image

[image]

Comment: so....use ajax?

Comment: You can use `$_SESSION`

Comment: Don't think php is the right way. Why you don't use JS/jaax as Manav told you

Answer (score 1):

Search for ajax. For example (with jQuery)

```
$.ajax({ url: "website.com/phpfile.php?var=" + encodeURIComponent(value),
    cache: false,
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(response)
    {
         // do something with the result, or omit the whole success if not needed
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
         // notify user about error?
    }
});
```

There are easier, more oriented versions, like $.post or $.get
Check out here: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/